# start jQuery Alert on page load

Tags: jquery, html, web

I got no exp or any knowledge in jquery but I want to put an alert on page load. 
I got this code 
        
    
    Examples of using jQuery Alerts

```
<script src="jquery.alerts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="jquery.alerts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<!-- Example script -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
$("#basic_button").click( function() {
jAlert('Example of a basic alert box in jquery', 'jquery basic alert box');
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>
<input id="basic_button" type="button" value="Show Basic Alert" />
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

How to set it on page load?

Comment: Also read about http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    jAlert('Example of a basic alert box in jquery', 'jquery basic alert box');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should include jQuery library in your page.you can get from here :- [jquery Library](http://jquery.com/download/)

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready( function() {

        alert('Your Message');

        });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    jAlert('Example of a basic alert box in jquery', 'jquery basic alert box');
});
```

or You can use Window onload

```
window.onload=function(){
    jAlert('Example of a basic alert box in jquery', 'jquery basic alert box');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#basic_button").click( function() {
   jAlert('Example of a basic alert box in jquery', 'jquery basic alert box');
});
```

This will be executed when `button` with `id` as `basic_button` is clicked if you want to dispaly it on page load use

```
$(document).ready( function() {
   jAlert('Example of a basic alert box in jquery', 'jquery basic alert box');
});
```

PS: I will advise to read some basic [**jQuery tutorials**](https://learn.jquery.com/) before jumping into coding.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** Passing a function into `$(func)` is a shortcut for `$(document).ready(func);`

```
$(function(){

alert("Page loaded");

});
```

Comment: Alert will appear on click on `button` and not on page load.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple do as below :

```
$(document).ready( function() {

  alert("Load Successfully");
});
```

Please do not forget to add jquery reference in head part.

If you are looking for jAlert then try as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Examples of using jQuery Alerts</title>
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.draggable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="jquery.alerts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="jquery.alerts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<!-- Example script -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {

   jAlert('Test');

});
</script>
</head>
<body>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="jquery.alerts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="jquery.alerts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

here you go.

```
<!-- Example script -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
jAlert('Example of a basic alert box in jquery', 'jquery basic alert box');
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>
<input id="basic_button" type="button" value="Show Basic Alert" />
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**`$( document ).ready()`**

A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside $( document ).ready() will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute. Code included inside $( window ).load(function() { ... }) will run once the entire page (images or iframes), not just the DOM, is ready.

```
// A $( document ).ready() block.
$( document ).ready(function() {
alert( "ready!" );
});
```

OR

```
// A $( document ).ready() block.
$( document ).ready(function() {
console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

Experienced developers sometimes use shorthand for $( document ).ready(). If you are writing code that people who aren't experienced with jQuery may see, it's best to use the long form.

```
// Shorthand for $( document ).ready()
$(function() {
console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `click` handler. Also, seem like you're missing jQuery library, you can add this before your `jAlert` plugin:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.alerts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="jquery.alerts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready( function() {
         jAlert('Example of a basic alert box in jquery', 'jquery basic alert box');
     });
</script>
```